# the type arguments for method 'System.linq.Enumerable.singleOrDefault<TSource>' cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

the type arguments  for method '`System.linq.Enumerable.singleOrDefault<TSource>'` cannot be inferred from the usage

```
  var sum = res.sp_GetSum_OrderpriceV0(int.Parse(Orderid)).SingleOrDefault();
    //error here
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first, You have to convert the `Orderid` to `int` then use of it in the linq query. For example:

```
int orderId_int= Convert.ToInt32(Orderid);
var sum = res.sp_GetSum_OrderpriceV0(int.Parse(orderId_int)).SingleOrDefault();
```